# Remove In Case Of Emergency association

Tags: contacts, 4.4-kitkat, sony-xperia, emergency-calls

I was setting up the contacts on my Xperia Z3 (Kit Kat) and entered in my wife as the In Case Emergency contact. However now if I dial her number normally (e.g. from the phone app) it comes up as "In Case Emergency" on the screen. Messages from her in the Messaging app appear as though they have been sent from "In Case Emergency". It appears as though just her mobile number has been associated this way as if I dial her home number then her details are displayed correctly.

I have tried turning off and on, and clearing out the data for the contacts app. I have tried adding and removing her and other contacts from the In Case Emergency contact list.

Given that she is the person I call and send messages to the most it would be nice to have her actual name displayed! Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I just have a regular contact as `ICE (name)`, but no special feature on my phone for designation

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused by a contact named "In Case Emergency" that was not appearing on my phone but was in my gmail contact lists when I looked on the web client. Removing this contact fixed the problem.